How can I join the paper to the hand so it moves with it when I animate the bone
I tried to use join object and also parent the paper to the hand mesh but it didn’t work…
First image-I want it to glue like this:
Second image-Hand moving without paper:



When you parent the paper to the hand, it will follow the hand's origin relative to its location and rotation like every object parented to another does in Object Mode.
The problem here is, the deformation by an armature works below object level, so to say. Which means, the mesh of the hand changes, but the object data like location and rotation remain unaltered.
You can see this in the following example (forgive me my very crude hand model and posing skills). The card is between the fingers but parented to the object, the fingers are animated with bones so the card stays in place while the fingers move, because the origin of the hand does not move. Only when the complete hand is moved by its parent object the armature, then the card moves and rotates with it:

What you would usually do in this case is parent the card to a bone which it should stick to. To do that, in Object Mode first select the card, then Shift + select the armature so that the armature is the active object, then go to Pose Mode, select the bone which should be the parent of the card and press Ctrl+P > Set Parent To > Bone.

Now the card moves with the bone it is parented to:

Another possible way, but this is mostly used if you have no bones to parent an object to for example when you are deforming a mesh with shape keys, is to parent the card to vertices of the hand.
This is done like that: first select the hand in Object Mode, then switch into Edit Mode, select 3 vertices (or more if you want, but at least 3 are needed to calculate the orientation), then hold Ctrl and select the card (while still in Edit Mode). Then press Ctrl+P, there will be no options displayed or any message, but now the card is parented to the 3 vertices.

Note: in this scenario where I place the card on the already deformed hand I have to enable the Edit Mode and On Cage display options in the armature modifier so that the deformed mesh will be shown in Edit Mode.

The end result is almost the same like before with the parenting to the bone, however this is just an example. The card movement could be vastly different since parenting to the bone only moves the card rigid with the bone, while the mesh can be heavily deformed by an armature and therefore the card movement by vertices might visually differ very much from the bone movement. As I said, this is often more useful for shapekeys where there are no bones to parent to, but on the other hand sometimes you want to ensure that a child object follows the deformation correctly and not only the bone itself.

